# Proof by induction: $\sum^{2n-1}_{i=1} (2i-1)=(2n-1)^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$\sum^{2n-1}_{i=1} (2i-1)=(2n-1)^2$

I get stuck after proving the base case is true. Usually with induction I assume the left and right sides are equal at some k, but I'm not sure how to approach this problem since the left side is a sum.

Comment: Write the $k+1$ case in the sum as the sum for the $k$ case plus the remaining term, i.e., you'll get something like $S_{k+1}=S_k + (2(2(k+1)-1)-1 \\ = S_k + 4(k+1)-3$.

Answer (score 3):

You can notice that, when you replace $n$ with $n+1$, the sum contains the sum for $n$, with some further terms; for instance
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i = \biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n i\biggr)+(n+1)
$$
In your case,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2(n+1)-1} (2i-1) =
\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} (2i-1) =
\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} (2i-1)\biggr)
+(2\cdot2n-1)+(2\cdot(2n+1)-1)
$$
because the last summation misses the last *two* terms, the one for $i=2n$ and the one for $i=2n+1$.

Now you can replace the summation by $(2n-1)^2$ because of the induction hypothesis and try to see whether this produces the same as $(2(n+1)-1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}(2i-1)=(2n-1)^2$, then\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{2(n+1)-1}(2i-1)&=\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}(2i-1)\\&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}(2i-1)\right)+(4n-1)+(4n+1)\\&=(2n-1)^2+8n\\&=4n^2+4n+1\\&=(2n+1)^2.\end{align}